# Search inside List<T> for 2 columns that match

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to store objects in a List and have therefore
created a class with 3 properties; prop1. prop2 and prop3.

To add a new Item to my List I'm using for example

```
_st.Add(new Bld(100,20,"Test1");
_st.Add(new Bld(101,20,"Test2");
_st.Add(new Bld(102,54,"Test3");
```

Now: How can I search the list to get the index of an Item
that contains `myObj.prop2 = 20 AND myObj.prop3="Test1"`?

I've tried something like

```
_st.Where(tk => tk.prop1 == 1000 AND tk.Title == "Test1");
```

but this obviously doesn't work.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) method, and use `&&` instead of `AND`

```
_st.FindIndex(tk => tk.prop1 == 1000 && tk.Title == "Test1");
```

Comment: " get the **index** of an Item"

Answer (score 2):

To get the index of an Item Use **[FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)** method e.g.

```
_st.FindIndex(tk => tk.prop1 == 1000 && tk.Title == "Test1")
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 1):

SQL operators need not apply:

```
_st.Where(tk => tk.prop1 == 1000 && tk.Title == "Test1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try this: [FindIndex Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)

```
int index = _st.FindIndex(tk => tk.prop1 == 1000 && tk.Title == "Test1");
```

OR

```
int index1 = _st.Select((tk, index) => new { _st = tk, Index = index })
          .FirstOrDefault(tk => tk._st.prop1 == 1000 && tk._st.Name_ar == "Test1")
          .Index;
```